# "undefined" result after getting data from web service in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I'm sorry to bother you but I need help with this.
I want to get data back from Web Services in asp.net . I have called the service from the next JQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#btn").click(function () {

            var name = "";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{null}",
                url: "EmployeeInfo.asmx/GetEmployeeInfo",
                dataTyp: "json",
                success: function (res) {
                    name = res.d;
                    alert(name);

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });


        }); 
    });
```

I will get Employee name from DB but the next code is just for testing:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetEmployeeInfo()
    { 
        return "John";
    }
```

The problem is I'm getting "undefined" as a result from the retrieved value. am I missing something?

Thank you all for your efforts and help

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var name = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "*youepage.aspx*/GetEmployeeInfo",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                name = response.d;
                alert(name);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

For testing:
in the same page (your .aspx) go to code behind and write:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string GetEmployeeInfo()
    {
        return "jack";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately the same result (undefined) :(

Comment: Updating the answer toperfect working example, change the url to your .aspx page name and add the code behind

Comment: I don't want it to access the same page, I want it to call the method in .asmx file.